# How to manipulate this Dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image]

I want to manipulate the above pandas Dataframe to find the percentage of 'Days to 1st login < 14 days" by each 'Sales Chain' and grouped by every day, to have the answer like: "On 1st May, 20% users from web sale while 5% users from other sale channel logged in within 14 days"

So then I could plot the line chart of all the sale channels over the time based on these percentage figures.

Please advise me how to do so. Thank you.

Comment: Can you add desired output of input `Extract of the Dataframe`?

Answer (score 0):

You can have the counts (instead of the percentage) with:

```
dataframe['amount'] = 1

output = dataframe.groupby(['Opened','Sales chain', 'Days to 1st login < 14 days'],as_index = False).sum()
```

Then calculating the percentage seems relatively easy. If your dataframe isn't to big, you can iterate over rows:

```
for i in range(len(output)/2):
    temp = output.amount[i]+output.amount[i+1]
    output.amount[i] /= 1.*temp
    output.amount[i+1] /= 1.*temp
```

I hope this code works, because as I don't have a code creating your dataframe I can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use crosstab

```
In [29]: df
Out[29]: 
    Opened       Sales   Chain Days to 1st login <14
0   140936  02.05.2015  Others                   Yes
1   140937  02.05.2015  Others                    No
2   140938  02.05.2015    Aspa                    No
3   140939  02.05.2015  Others                   Yes
4   140940  02.05.2015  Others                    No
5   140941  02.05.2015  Others                    No
6   140942  02.05.2015    Aspa                    No
7   140943  02.05.2015  Others                   Yes
8   140944  02.05.2015     Web                    No
9   140945  01.05.2015     Web                    No
10  140946  01.05.2015     Web                    No

In [30]: df_counts = pd.crosstab([df['Sales'], df['Chain']], df['Days to 1st login <14'])

In [31]: df_counts
Out[31]: 
Days to 1st login <14  No  Yes
Sales      Chain              
01.05.2015 Web          2    0
02.05.2015 Aspa         2    0
           Others       3    3
           Web          1    0

In [32]: 100 * df_counts['Yes'] / (df_counts['Yes'] + df_counts['No'])
Out[32]: 
Sales       Chain 
01.05.2015  Web        0.0
02.05.2015  Aspa       0.0
            Others    50.0
            Web        0.0
dtype: float64
```

or much simpler with *groupby* and *apply*

```
In [33]: df.groupby(['Sales', 'Chain']).apply(lambda x: 100 * len(x[x['Days to 1st login <14'] == 'Yes']) / len(x))
Out[33]: 
Sales       Chain 
01.05.2015  Web        0.0
02.05.2015  Aspa       0.0
            Others    50.0
            Web        0.0
dtype: float64
```